# When I delete Text box in tkinter, a blank line is always left

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

def hi(event):
    print(txt.get('1.0',END))
    txt.delete('1.0',END)

root = Tk()

lbl = Label(root, text="client")
lbl.pack()

txt = Text(root, height=10, width=50)
txt.pack()
txt.bind('<Return>', hi)


btn = Button(root, text="OK")
btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

When I delete Text widget contents, a blank line is left. How to prevent that?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The built-in bindings cause a newline to be inserted when you press the return key. When you create a binding, your bound function is called *before* the default behavior. Thus, when you press return, your function deletes everything, and then the default action inserts a newline.

If you want to prevent the default action from happening, your function needs to return the string `break`:

```
def hi(event):
    print(txt.get('1.0',END))
    txt.delete('1.0',END)
    return "break"
```

Answer (score 2):

What happens is that the text widget still gets the return you entered. Binding the Enter does not inhibits the propagation of the event after your function ends, unless you alter it to cancel event propagation by returning the break string, like this:

```
def hi(event):
    print(txt.get('1.0',END))
    txt.delete('1.0',END)
    return 'break'
```

Answer (score 1):

You must ask tkinter not to propagate  that event to other handlers as follows:

```
from tkinter import *

def hi(event):
    print(txt.get('1.0',END))
    txt.delete('1.0',END)
    return "break"


root = Tk()

lbl = Label(root, text="client")
lbl.pack()

txt = Text(root, height=10, width=50)
txt.pack()
txt.bind('<Return>', hi)


btn = Button(root, text="OK")
btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```